# Boundary conditions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

$\displaystyle -\frac{c}{2} f^2 + f^3 + \frac{1}{2} \left( f' \right)^2 = Af + B$

with the conditions: when $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ then we should have $f \rightarrow 0, \ f' \rightarrow 0$

My text says that it follows that $A = B = 0$. I can see why $B$ has to be zero but I do not get it for $A$.  Maybe it is something very simple but I am stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the book you are using? I'm assuming you are solving the KdV equation using a travelling wave ansatz which then yields the above ODE. If so, then the problem is often given with the extra initial data $f'' \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ (which follows directly from the conditions $f, f' \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$), which means at the previous step when you have $$f'' - 3f^{2} - cf = A$$ you necessarily have $A = 0$.

Comment: Yes I am trying to solve the KdV. Ahhh. Yes, I get it. It was that simple. Thank you very much for the reply.